# How do I move a local DynamoDB database to the AWS cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I have a static set of data I want to get into AWS DynamoDB. I have downloaded the local version of DynamoDB and tested the code that generates the data on it, and now I have the database with all the data locally.

My question is: Is there an efficient way to move the local database into the cloud? I know that I can transfer a CSV file to S3 and use a data pipe from there. Is there a better way without exporting the data and re-importing it?

The data is not that much, about 5 GB (so not Amazon Snowball type thing).

Thanks!

Comment: Exporting and reimporting is your only option. Your dataset is small enough to be imported through a utility like https://github.com/bchew/dynamodump. Of course you can use datapipeline if you want to.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'll do then.