# How do I export data (tables and data) from AWS DynamoDB and import into a local DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, import, export, amazon-dynamodb

I would like to create an isolated local environment (running on linux) for development and testing.

How can I export data (~10 tables and ~few hundred items of data) from AWS DynamoDB ind import into a local DynamoDB instance?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [dynamodump](https://github.com/bchew/dynamodump).

First export from AWS to your local machine:

```
python dynamodump.py -m backup -r REGION_NAME -s TABLE_NAME
```

Next import to [DynamoDB Local](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html):

```
python dynamodump.py -m restore -r local -s TABLE_NAME --host localhost --port 8000 --accessKey a --secretKey a
```

Finally verify the new local tables:

```
aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

> Important: If your provisioned read / write capacity on AWS is
>   on-demand, you must manually change the ReadCapacityUnits and
>   WriteCapacityUnits values in the saved schema.json file from step 1
>   from '0' to '1' to avoid the following error: Table read and write
>   throughput must be at least 1, and cannot be null

Comment: Thanks for the tool, but the method `restore` should be like this:
```dynamodump -m restore -r local -s sourceTableName -d lobalTableName --host localhost --port 8000```

Comment: Make sure to specify accessKey and secretKey, otherwise this path will be used ~/.aws/credentials. Almost messed up the dev database ...

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried this, but you should be able to use the CLI.

First extract the data into local JSON files

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name MYLIVETABLE --output json > pathtofile/MYLIVETABLE.json
```

And then load that data into your local DynamoDB instance

```
aws dynamodb batch-write-item --table-name MYLOCALTABLE --request-items file://pathtofile/MYLIVETABLE.json --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

Comment: The second command won't work: --table-name is not a supported option for the batch-write-item command. See: [aws cli docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/batch-write-item.html)

Comment: batch-write-item requires the data format which is not same as the output of DB scan

Comment: As the other comments already said, this solution may work but it needs more then just these two commands

Answer (score -3):

AWS do provide the local version for dynamoDB. More details below:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html

create  the local copy  as mentioned above and transfer it in another local DynamoDB instance ..

Comment: this does not answer the question.

Comment: create  the local copy  as mentioned above and transfer it in another local DynamoDB instance ..

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is 100% correct, but 0% helpful. I am aware that Amazon provide a local version for DynamoDB. I have it. Hence I asked the question. -- given I am aware of and have a local DynamoDB instance, how can I export from AWS DynamoDB and import anatomy local DynamoDB, the one I am aware of and already have running?

Comment: Well , in that case below is the only thing it seems possible.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37810936/how-do-i-move-a-local-dynamodb-database-to-the-aws-cloud